# Why is the set $\{0.5\} \times (0.5,1]$ not open in the order topology of $I\times I = [0,1]\times [0,1]$

Tags: general-topology

In the book of *General Topology* by Munkes, at page 90, it is given that (Example 3),

[image]

However, I didn't get it why the set $\{0.5\} \times (0.5,1]$ is not open in $I\times I$ in the order topology.

I mean, consider the interval $( (0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 1] ) = \{0.5\} \times (0.5, 1]$, hence it is open.

Answer (score 0):

The set $A= ((\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}), (\frac{1}{2},1 )]$ is not an *open* interval but a half-open one. We only know in an ordered space that sets $(a,b)$ (note the two open boundaries), where $a,b \in X$ are open as well as sets of the form $[\min(X), a), (a,\max(X)]$$A \in X$, so closed sides are only allowed for two special points (that need not exist), $\min(X)$ and $\max(X)$ (or these would not be in any open interval. so in no open sets, hence the exception).

In this case $p=(\frac{1}{2},1)$ is not an interior point of $A$. Because if it were, there would have to be an open interval $J$ (as $p$ is not the $(0,0) = \min(I \times I)$ nor $(1,1) = \max(I \times I)$ these are its basic neighbourhoods) with $p \in ((a,b), (c,d))=J \subset A$.
But then $c > \frac{1}{2}$ (definition of lexicographic order) and there are points in $J$ that are not in $A$, contradiction). Munkres has a picture IIRC.